# Build iOS app in Mac hosted in virtual machine

Tags: ios, build

I am trying to create an iOS app but i don't have apple computer, is it possible to build iOS app inside a Mac hosted in a virtual machine ?

Actually I have an application's Android version and i need to create a iOS version too

Comment: Google `Build iOS app in Mac hosted in virtual machine`

Comment: I would build a Hackintosh instead and dual-boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to have hackintosh if you're desperate.
But like the other guy said, you can google it(the way to use VM as Hackintosh).
it's common thing now to build an iOS app on virtual machines (because macs is bit pricey ...) so i think there will be so many example to do that.

though if you want to publish your app or even simulate it on devices, you have to create a developer account to get license,provisions, keys, etc..
i heard it cost you about 100$ or so to join with dev account.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

Download iOS from some torrent and run it on VirtualBox locally, breaking Apple's SLA.

Rent a Mac from one of the following providers, costs $20 - 50 per month

- https://www.macstadium.com
- https://macincloud.com
- https://xcloud.me